# 鍵作成や証明書作成時(ca署名)にエラーメッセージのみを表示したい

Tags: openssl

以下のそれぞれのコマンドで出力される通常のメッセージを抑止し、エラーメッセージのみ画面出力する方法があればご教示願います。

**■鍵作成**

```
openssl genrsa -out test.key -aes256 -passout pass:＜任意＞ 2048
```

**■証明書作成**

```
openssl ca  -batch -policy policy_anything -out /etc/pki/CA/test.crt -passin pass:＜任意＞ -infiles ＜CSRファイル名＞
```

試してみたところ、通常のメッセージも標準エラー出力になっているようで、リダイレクトでは対応出来ないようでした。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースコード（[genrsa.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/8bf37709a471bb31d2e1f5b4b3796fb3e6dce4df/apps/genrsa.c)、[ca.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/8bf37709a471bb31d2e1f5b4b3796fb3e6dce4df/apps/ca.c)）をあたってみましたが、どうやらもとのコードの時点ですべて標準エラーに出力しているようで、分ける方法は存在しないようでした。

どうしても出力を削りたければ、あとから何らかのプログラムで必要でないテキストを削るようにする必要があると思います。